# Umbraco 8 Front-end instance not updating

Tags: azure, umbraco, umbraco8

I have an Umbraco 8 application v8.14.1 which is running on Azure and is setup to run as Admin and Public instances using 2 App Services.

Admin is the master instance and used to make any CMS content changes.

Public is purely used to serve content.

I have configured these as Load Balanced Azure Web Apps using the following documentation - https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Fundamentals/Setup/Server-Setup/Load-Balancing/azure-web-apps-v8

Everything was working correctly for several months, I make a change in the Admin backoffice and this would be visible in the Public site within a few seconds.

However, all of a sudden this stopped working and changes made in the Admin backoffice would not be visible in the Public site, even after a couple of hours.

I had to clear all of the caches using Diplo's God Mode, make a new content change and this correctly displayed on the Public site.

My question is, what went wrong and is there any way to stop this from happening?

The logs did not show any errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I find the indexes are often out of whack and the cache can get desynched too.
For cache, it can sometimes be if you have something setup that  affects cache in hangfire, and it happens to be running on public too this can make the public instances cache number higher than the master, and so when master signas a cache change the public instance thinks it already has it.

Indexes I have no idea. Ours is setup according to their specs and the indexes are often corrupted.